# How to construct the order? How to sort tuples?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

This question asks me to design a deterministic algorithm that would run in theta(n log n) time to do the following:

There was a race, and the order in which the racers finished will be decided by this info: each runner will report his own number,a, and the runner immediately ahead of him, b. <a,b> pairs. The winner will report b as null.
If the input of the algorithm is n such pairs of <a,b>s, how can we design an algorithm to decide the order in which the runners finished the race?
Hint says use sorting but if I sort based on the first values, a's, then finding out about the second value still makes the algorithm O(n^2). If I sort based on the b's, then searching for a's will cause the algorithm be O(n^2).
How can I do this in theta(n log n)?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to sort based on second values. For example if the input is (9, null), (6,7), (2,9),(5,10),(7,5), (10,2). After sorting it will look like this: (9, null) (10,2), (7,5),(6,7), (2,9), (5,10). Will start with tuple whose second value is null: 9 is the 1st place. Now I need to find who has 9 as its b value? At this point sorting earlier doesn't help me at all. I will run into the same issue with each tuple and go back and forth on the array of tuples. So, the time complexity requirement will not be satisfied. Or sorting based on just first values or just second values will not help me.

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing

Comment: Are the numbers of the racers chosen uniquely between `0` and `n-1` (if `n` is the total number of racers)? Please clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the racers' numbers are chosen from the set `{1, ..., n}` (where `n` is the total number of racers):

1. Instantiate a 0-based array `arr` of size `n + 1`.
2. For each pair `(a,b)`, do `arr[b] := a`, interpreting `null` as `0`.
3. Starting from `i := 0`, do `n` times: `i := arr[i]`. The assigned values of `i` are exactly the racers' numbers in the correct order.

This clearly has time complexity `O(n)`. So in order to get `Θ(n log n)` (*Theta*, not *O*), just do an irrelevant task as Step 4 which takes `Θ(n log n)`, like sorting `n` numbers using Heap Sort and ignoring the result.

---

If you cannot assume that the racers' numbers are chosen from `{1, ..., n}`, you first create an associative array from the racers' numbers to `{1, ..., n}` (and a normal array for the other direction) and then proceed as before, using the associative array for translating the racers' numbers into the array indices. A hash table won't do the job since it has `Θ(n)` (non-amortized) lookup time, which would result in `Θ(n^2)`. Use a self-balancing binary search tree as associate array instead, which has `Θ(log n)` lookup time. The creation of the tree also takes `Θ(n log n)`, so there you get your `Θ(n log n)` in total even without the dummy step 4 above.